# Could not find fetcher.properties on classpath

Tags: spring

I am working to implement RSS feed using the spring integration as mentioned in the  article http://comdynamics.net/blog/295/spring-integration-rss-feed-reader/. However, when I run the application I am getting the following error:

**Could not find fetcher.properties on classpath**

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Can you verify that you have the folder that contains this property file in the classpath of the project? You would have to look at .classpath file to verify this.

Ideally you would want to keep this file in a config folder and must be added to the classpath just like your source folder.

Answer (score 1):

create an empty file named fetcher.properties on classpath. You don't have to add any entry to it.That will solve the problem